# how to disable spell checker for Android AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I've searched for this problem but not found any answers for my case.
I have an AutoCompleteTextView and some strings as suggestions (city names).

Android marks them with red line.

[image]

I think it's Android's spell checker. How can I prevent spell checking?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found the best solution:

```
android:inputType="textPhonetic"
```

Answer (score 7):

Put this in your XML:

```
android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: This seems better `textPhonetic` as I can't tell what phonetic is meant to be used for.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure but

You can use `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"` to get rid of suggestions and `android:autoText` to `false` for autocompletetextview.

The other possible way out will be to use `android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"`

You can have look at [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#autoText)

Comment: @downvoter can you please help me understand the reason for a downvote ? it will be a big help for me to understand this