# How to disable the spell checker on an AutoSuggestBox

Tags: wpf, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I would like to disable the spell checker in a Windows Phone 8.1 application, which is on by default on an AutoSuggestBox, but not desired:

[image: Screenshot of app in emulator]

The markup of the control:

```
<AutoSuggestBox 
    Name="txtOrgunit" 
    TextChanged="txtOrgunit_TextChanged"
    SuggestionChosen="txtOrgunit_SuggestionChosen">
</AutoSuggestBox>
```

How can I achieve that the `IsSpellCheckEnabled` property goes false on the internal textbox from markup or from code?

Existing solutions I have found either deal with the same problem on other platforms (like this:

[How can I disable the spell checker on text inputs on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3416867/how-can-i-disable-the-spell-checker-on-text-inputs-on-the-iphone)

and this:

[how to disable spell checker for Android AutoCompleteTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703286/how-to-disable-spell-checker-for-android-autocompletetextview))

or they are unwieldy rocket science, like this:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/c2139520-26e9-4a74-819d-defb4e20857c/how-to-disable-spell-check-grammer-in-autosuggestbox?forum=wpdevelop

**EDIT**: After applying the solution proposed in the first answer verbatim, the OP goal is achieved, but the functionality of the control is broken (the event is raised, the itemssource ends up with 30 items, but none of them is shown - no "dropdown" appears any more). Therefore I give the source code of the `txtOrgunit_TextChanged` handler below:

```
private void txtOrgunit_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
    {
        var ui = sender.Text.Trim().ToUpperInvariant();
        var matches = new List<IdAndCaption>();
        var count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Com.MasterdataBasic.Orgunits.Length; ++i)
        {
            var cand = Com.MasterdataBasic.Orgunits[i];
            var cap = String.Format("{0} {1}", cand.Abbrev, cand.LongCap);
            if (cap.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(ui))
            {
                var ele = new IdAndCaption() { Id = cand.OrgID, Caption = cap };
                matches.Add(ele);
                ++count;
                /* UX decided it unreasonable to have the user scroll through more...
                 * should type more letters to restrict further */
                if (count >= 30) break;
            }
        }
        sender.ItemsSource = matches;
        Rec.Report.OrgID = -1;
    }    
}
```

I verified that when I remove the style tag from the autosuggestbox, the autosuggest functionality is restored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems the `AutoSuggestBox` control doesn't have the property `IsSpellCheckEnabled` so in order to do that you would need to create a `ControlTemplate` with a `TextBox` control that does contain the property `IsSpellCheckEnabled` and set it to **False** there.

What you want to do first is create a `ResourceDictionary` in your project if you haven't already got one:

[image: resourcedictionary]

For the purpose of this example I have given mine a name of **Styles.xaml**.

The code below will give you more or less what you want. You may want to adapt certain `Setter` properties but going off the example in the link you provided in your question I've cobbled together this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:AppNamespace">

<!-- modified default style for AutoSuggestBox -->
<Style x:Name="AutoSuggestBoxStyle" TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource TextControlMarginThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestListViewItemMargin}" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource TextBoxForegroundThemeBrush}" />
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="AutoSuggestBox">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="Orientation">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Landscape"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Portrait"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <TextBox x:Name="TextBox"
                         IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
                         PlaceholderText="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PlaceholderText}"
                         Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Header}"
                         Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                         ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="False"
                         Canvas.ZIndex="0"
                         Margin="0" />
                    <Popup x:Name="SuggestionsPopup">
                        <Border x:Name="SuggestionsContainer"
                              Background="{ThemeResource AutoSuggestBackgroundThemeBrush}"
                              BorderBrush="{ThemeResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{ThemeResource TextControlBorderThemeThickness}">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TranslateTransform x:Name="UpwardTransform"/>
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                            <ListView x:Name="SuggestionsList"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemsSource}"
                              ItemTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemTemplate}"
                              ItemTemplateSelector="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemTemplateSelector}"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ItemContainerStyle}"
                              RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                                <ListView.RenderTransform>
                                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="ListItemOrderTransform"/>
                                </ListView.RenderTransform>
                            </ListView>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Copy the  XAML into the **Styles.xaml**.

You now need to reference to this new `ResourceDictionary`. This can either be done in your `App.xaml` or the page itself.

In the `App.xaml` this is how you would reference:

```
<Application
    x:Class="App6.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App6">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

</Application>
```

> If for whatever reason you can't get to the XAML in your `App.xaml` then do a search for `<Application` and you should be able to get to it that way.

Then in the page itself you can create an `AutoSuggestBox` and reference to the *AutoSuggestBoxStyle*:

```
<AutoSuggestBox Style="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle}"/>
```

In my example I have two `AutoSuggestBoxes`:

```
<StackPanel>
    <AutoSuggestBox Style="{StaticResource AutoSuggestBoxStyle}"/>
    <AutoSuggestBox></AutoSuggestBox>
</StackPanel>
```

This is how it looks in my emulator:

[image: emulator example]

As you can see the top `AutoSuggestBox` which references to the style doesn't show the red line like the bottom one does.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! I followed your instruction and achieved what I needed. But now the tests fail - the actual autosuggest functionality is broken. When I remove the style attribute from the target autosuggestbox, it works again. there has to be some data binding-related stuff missing in that template. see edit.

Comment: probably, the template needs that `<Popup x:Name="SuggestionsPopup">` part... going to try to figure that out, it is truncated in that MSDN article... is there no way to specify only part of a template, and inherit the rest from the built-in one?

Comment: It probably is to do with the popup element. I'm not at my Dev machine till tomorrow so can't do any testing but I'll have a look when I get back to it and update my answer if I manage to figure it out.

Comment: I found the generic.xaml from the windows phone kit on my local C: drive, extracted the complete autosuggestbox style template from there, added our property, and updated the answer with it. works fine.